# store a randomized integer from a request to property using groovy scripting

Tags: java, json, rest, groovy, soapui

I want to store a randomized integer that has been called out in the request body and store it in test case Property so that it can be passed as a body parameter in the next request.

for example:
Request1:
`id_num = randomNumeric(10)`

Properties:
`id_num = 1234567890`

Request2:
`trfered_IDNum = ${#TestCase#id_num}`

Answer (score 1):

The Structure looks like below,

```
Project
  |---TestSuite
         |-------TestCase
                   |------RestRequestTestStep1
                   |------RestRequestTestStep2
                   |------GroovyScript
```

Let's start with some assumptions.

1. RestRequestTestStep1 Response Body has below fields  :

   ```
                        {"Resp1Field1Key":"Resp1Field1Value",
                         "Resp1Field2Key":"Resp1Field2Value"}
   ```
2. RestRequestTestStep2 Request Body has below fields  :

   ```
                         {"Resp2Field1Key":"Resp2Field1Value",
                          "Resp2Field2Key":"Resp2Field2Value"}
   ```
3. Resp1Field1Value and Resp1Field2Value from first response will be substituted to Resp2Field1Value and Resp2Field2Value of second request.
4. RestRequestTestStep2 body should be as below as we will be substituting values from the testCase Property that will be set in the groovy script once first request is completed.

   {
   "Resp2Field1Key":"${#TestCase#Resp2Field1Value}",
   "Resp2Field2Key":"${#TestCase#Resp2Field2Value}"
   }

**The Code..rather Script :**  The groovy script can be placed under the same Test Case and should do below,

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//Substitute with appropriate testSuiteName,testCaseName,testStepName1 and testStepName1 as per the Project Structure you have.

def testSuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("testSuiteName")
        def testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName("testCaseName")
        def testStep1 = testCase.getTestStepByName("testStepName1")
        def testStep2 = testCase.getTestStepByName("testStepName2")
        
       // Call the first REST Request
       testStep1.run(testRunner, context)       
    
        def response = testStep1.testRequest.response.responseContent
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

       //Assign it to a testCase Property to grab for second Rest Request

         if (jsonSlurper.size() > 0) {
            testCase.setPropertyValue("Resp1Field1Value",Resp1Field1Value)
            testCase.setPropertyValue("Resp1Field2Value",Resp1Field2Value)
            );

       //Call the second Rest Request

       testStep2.run(testRunner, context)       
    
        def response = testStep2.testRequest.response.responseContent
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

     // Perform Validation/assertion as desired
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these 2 lines in your groovy script before second request in the same test case

```
def id_num = (new Random().nextInt(100000000)).toString()
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "id_num", id_num  )
log.info id_num
```

[image]

Now since you have saved the value in a **testcase** properties in a soap step, you can use like below in the next request within same testcase

```
${#TestCase#id_num}
```

[image]

This way it will automatically replace the value once you run. To see the values replacement in soap UI , you can see the Raw Tab

check this out below.. the value got replaced

[image]